# Java webdevelopment IDE/Server/Documentation

Tags: java

I have been using PHP (OOP) with various Frameworks for all my webdevelopment projects for the last few years. Next year I'll have to learn Java as part of CS university course, so I thought it may be a good idea to switch to Java for some of my smaller webdevelopment projects, so that I can get to know Java in advance.

What do I need to use Java for backend web development? What IDE/Server software/etc. should I use? What frameworks are available and which documentations could one recommend?

I know this is strictly not a Stackoverflow question, but I'd really like to hear the opinion  of the very professional community here at Stackoverflow!

Comment: [Play](http://www.playframework.org/) and eclipse.

Comment: @Raynos: Do you want to add your suggestion as an answer? Because I finally also decided to use the Play framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The web development component of Java is called Java EE. You should look into that.

As IDE you can use [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/), [Netbeans](http://netbeans.org/), etc. (you can download versions that are specifically aimed at Java EE development, with bundled servers like GlassFish or Tomcat).

Answer (score 0):

Use all of these technologies and learn what the terms mean: Servlet, JSP, JSTL, Filter, Tag library (create your own).

A very popular framework is Spring. Spring Core and Spring MVC has recreated most of the Java EE components but in a way that is easier to use.

The DWR library makes AJAX very easy.

Learn how to use Spring ORM, Hibernate or JPA.

Answer (score 0):

I also just want to add my own answere to show what I choose in the end to work with:

- IDE: [NetBeans](http://netbeans.org/)
- Framework [Play! Framework](http://www.playframework.org/)